# Qt. Нужна версия 4.8.2

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

История такая. Преподаватель рекомендовал версию qt 4.8.2. На официальном сайте можно через онлайн установщик скачать только пятую ветку. Совместимости у веток нет, насколько я знаю. Где найти 4.8.2? а то большинство команд из учебного пособия не работает, спасибо.

Comment: [Тут](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/) есть.

Comment: Рекомендуйте преподавателю вылезти из пещеры, Qt 4.8.2 мягко говоря устарела.

Comment: @ixSci Я-то Вас полностью поддерживаю, но старые люди ой как на критику болезненно реагируют. Боюсь такая рекомендация мне обеспечит 20 баллов  на все 4 года.